# Why we declare static variable in a class & the definition in outside of the class?

Tags: c++

We declare a `static` variable in a class and initialize the variable outside the class, but we use the variable within the function.

Anyone tell me the reason why?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: There's a general distinction in C++ between declaration and definition. It's possible to do both at once in some cases but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure but my guess is, because inside a class member variables are only declared. They are initialized through a constructor or other member functions.

This happens when an object is instantiated. However for static members, the objects need not be instantiated. Hence they need to be initialized once outside of the class.

**EDIT:**
Actually it is not necessary to initialize the static variables, but it is necessary to **define** them outside the class to allocate memory for them. Only after their definition, can they be initialized and then used in the program.

Comment: 1. Here the output value i is not the initialized value..
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class sample
{
 public:
 int i;
};
int main()
{
 sample s;
 cout<<s.i;
}
 2. What happen wen declare "static int i" within the class..
    is it doesn't allocate memory?

Comment: No memory is not allocated when it is declared inside the class. Memory is allocated when it is actually defined outside the class.

Comment: In the code you mentioned the variable i is initialized when the object s is instantiated through the constructor, not when it is declared in the class.

Comment: "I'm not sure but my guess is, because inside a class members are only declared." This has never been true of member functions, which are often defined and declared together in a class declaration. As of C++11, it's also not necessarily true of non-static data members.

Comment: @Casey Yes by members OP and I both implied variables and not functions. I have edited to clarify this. Can you elaborate on how we can define non-static data members in a class in C++11? (sorry I genuinely do not know about that)

Answer (score 10):

Because static variables need to have some storage allocated somewhere.

Let's take this for example:

```
struct Example
{
    static int counter;
    Example() { counter++; }
};
```

You can create as many `Example` instances as you want, but there will only ever be one `Example::counter` variable. It's basically a global variable in disguise. But where should it live? Back in the early days of C++, Stroustrup decided the solution to this was for you to explicitly choose one translation unit (i.e. `.cpp` file) and declare it there, just as you would a "real" global variable. So you need to do something like

```
// Only in one .cpp file
int Example::counter = 0;
```

(Of course, later on templates were invented, and weak symbols to go with them, which could have solved this awkward mess, but it was too late by then.)

Answer (score 2):

Since static members are shared between ALL instances of a class, they have to be defined in one and only one place. Really, they're global variables with some access restrictions.

If you try to define them in the header, they will be defined in every module that includes that header, and you'll get errors during linking as it finds all of the duplicate definitions.

Yes, this is at least partly a historical issue dating from cfront; a compiler could be written that would create a sort of hidden "static_members_of_everything.cpp" and link to that. However, it would break backwards compatibility, and there wouldn't be any real benefit to doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Static variable are allocated in different section of the memory using a standard mechanism.

If they are initialized in the class using constructors, then there may be some violation of the standard mechanism of the allocation of the static variables.

Comment: What 'standard mechanism'? What 'violation'? Who mentioned constructors? -1

Comment: By standard mechanism, I am referring to the facts that they are allocated in the data segment(bss) and can be initialized only at its definition and is independent of the object creation. Also a normal variable is initialized in a class using constructors(also methods), So one would have the doubt of why not initialize using constuctors, so i did mention constuctor !

Comment: You haven't answered my questioj about 'violation'; data in the bss can be initialized any time; and the fact that data is allocated in the data segment has nothing to do with constructors or `static.` This answer is just a salad.

Comment: My answer was just simply to make a clear distinction between a static variable and normal variable. And I never said it constructor is associated with static. By giving the instance of constructor, is similar to a 'differentiate beween a static and normal variable ' tool. By violation, I mean that the whole properties of static variables(definition or declaration) may not be followed if someone try to initialize static variables within the class and so the compiler does not allow it.

Comment: Data in the bss is initialized only once at its definition. Later it is simply just assignment.

Answer (score 0):

**Declaration** inside the class only declares the variable in that scope. **Definition** actually allocates the memory.

You use it inside the class functions because it's defined in that scope. Static variables initialization doesn't happen at the object creation time, but rather at application startup.